# How to display value of jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value of jquery in php form in popup.

my jquery is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function() {
 var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val(); 

 if(mobileNumber=="")
    {
  alert("Please Enter Mobile Number");
   }
  else
  {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('test'); ?>",
    data: {mobileNumber: mobileNumber},
        success: function(result){
            if(result){
            $("#enter-otp").modal('show');

            }
        }
});
  }
return false;
});

});
```

I want to print var mobileNumber value in enter-otp id popup in same page
so i write

```
           <?php echo $mobileNumber; ?>
```

but it is not showing

Comment: What do you mean JavaScript value in PHP, that is not possible unless you send the data via AJAX (or classic HTML form) to your PHP script!? You should just use JS to change the PHP generated HTML, maybe describe a little more what you want to do.

Comment: you shouldn't use PHP to echo the value since you are dealing with client-side variables.

Comment: then how to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enter value in  `enter-otp` **id** popup in same page. You dont want any PHP script you can do it by jquery only. (Although  You can write in success of ajax). Suppose you have div tag with id of `otp-div` inside `enter-otp`. You can write following code

```
success: function(result){
        if(result){
        $("#enter-otp").modal('show');
        $("#otp-div").html(mobileNumber);
        //OR ifotp-div inout attribute then use `val()`
        $("#otp-div").val(mobileNumber);

        }
    }
```

Comment: how to call  $("#otp-div").val(mobileNumber); value to other jquery function

Comment: You can do `$("#otp-div").val($("#mobileNumber").val())`. If you want it in other jquery function

Answer (score 0):

depending on what gives you back your "result"-variable, you can output data.

so if your "result"-variable gives you back something useful, you can take this data and put it in the html like this.

```
    success: function(result){
        if(result){
         $("#enter-otp").html(result).modal('show');
        }
    }
```

regarding to your edit, this would be a simple solution:

```
success: function(result){
    if(result){
     $("#enter-otp").html(mobileNumber).modal('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i picked up your code and run it on localhost. and after few changes, i got it working. to try following:

### test.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="mobileNumber" type="text" name="mobileNumber" value="" placeholder="">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="enter-otp" style="display: none; border: 1px solid red;"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function() {
  var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();

  if (mobileNumber == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Mobile Number");
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "result.php",
      data: { 'mobileNumber': mobileNumber },
      success: function(result) {
        if(result){
            $("#enter-otp").show();
            $("#enter-otp").html(result);
        } else {
            alert("no data received");
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});

});
</script>
```

### result.php

```
<?php 
    if( isset($_REQUEST['mobileNumber'] )){
        echo $mobileNumber = $_REQUEST['mobileNumber'];
    } else {
      echo "no data";
    }
  ?>
```